# Paste and cut in one keystroke?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to

- Select some text in a document in some undefined application.
- Paste the contents of the clipboard to have that text replaced (normally done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+v)
- Have the contents that was selected copied into the clipboard (like cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+x)

only using one shortcut?

I am basically searching for a way to "paste and replace".

Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that there is any easy way to do it without using something like an [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to copy what's on the clipboard, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to put what is selected into the clipboard, and then "write" the value that *was* on the clipboard.

My quick attempt, I *think* it works... If you have Autohotkey installed then put it in `pasteCopy.ahk` and double click the script. It will set up the new "copy" on <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>

```
!v:: ; Alt-v
oldClip = %clipboard%    ; store contents of clipboard
Send ^c                  ; copy selected text
ClipWait
newClip = %clipboard%    ; store new clipboard contents
clipboard = %oldClip%    ; set clipboard contents to how it was before copy
Send, ^v                 ; paste the current "old" clipboard contents
clipboard = %newClip%    ; set clipboard contents to "new" copied value
return
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats a life saver!

Comment: @AndersLindén let me know if it needs tweaking, there might be some quirks that need delays to deal with copying to and from the clipboard. As I say it seems to work for a first rough try.